# Sugar ORM Android

Tags: java, android, orm, sugarorm

Решил изучить эту ORM потому что на примерах она показалось мне легким. Так вот есть простой объект:

```
public class FavoriteModel extends SugarRecord {
    private String desc;

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
}
```

и пытаюсь сохранить:

```
    FavoriteModel model = new FavoriteModel();
    model.setFav_id(id);
    model.setDesc("Описание");
    model.setId(id);
    model.save();
```

выдает ошибку:

```
   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table FAVORITE_MODEL has no column named DESC (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO FAVORITE_MODEL(THIS0,ID,DESC) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

**UDP** при выполнение команды

```
ViewActivity.Account.count(ViewActivity.class)
```

выдает -1."Если таблица не инициализирована, возвращаемое значение будет -1." - прочитал я в статье одной но как инициализировать там не было

Comment: возможно слово DESC - заразервированое и столбец так называться не может, так как в SQL DESC - это операция сортировки по убыванию

Comment: @pavloff здравствуйте. Нет не думаю потому что у меня были и другие имена этого значения и все равно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня в gradle была зависимость:

```
implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
```

я поменял на

```
implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
```

и все